# How to stop a running query in SQL Workbench/J

Tags: sql-workbench-j

Is there a command or function to kill/stop a running query in SQL Workbench/J?
I searched through the user manual http://ensdemos.com/almudon.com/uploads/reports/SQLWorkbench-Manual.pdf
which does not seem to mention it.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the cancel button in the toolbar?

Comment: I could not see this option, I am using build 125, (2019-05-08), Java version: 1.8.0_251, (32 bit), on a Windows 10 machine. The toolbar does not seem to have this option.

Comment: The stop sign (turns red when a statement starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you accidently removed the "Cancel button" from the toolbar. You can get it back using "Tools » Configure toolbar". Then you can either use "Reset to default" or drag the button to the location you want.

But you don't really need the toolbar button, you can also do this through "SQL » Cancel" while the statement is running:

[image]